# Filter routes based on interface

Tags: eigrp, route-filter

In EIGRP is there a way to filter routes entering from a specific interface?

The intent is to protect the network core's routing table from receiving misconfigured or maliciously-inserted routes from branch locations.

For example, if a branch location hosting subnets in the 192.168.10.0/22 range is connected to a core router's Gig 0 interface we'd like to apply a filter on routes received from Gig 0 so that only routes in the 192.168.10.0/22 range are allowed through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify what routes exactly you want to receive from neighbor on specific interface by using **distribute-list** option:

```
(conf)# router eigrp 10
(config-router)# distribute-list 50 in Tunnel 3

access-list standard 50
permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

This short example displays how to accept only routes to network 192.168.1.0/24 from neighbors on Tunnel 3 interface.